# how to fix tooltip after highchart upgrade

Tags: highcharts

Since 2016 I used Highcharts-4.2.5, but when implementing some new functions, I upgraded to Highcharts-7.1.2. After that, Solid-gauge tooltip no longer displays the values. Only black boxes appear.
The code was in default, but already changed to force the formatting and display of the field, without success.
If I return to the previous version, they return to normal operation.

![1]: https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipP3gJTQoAlJNM5tB3VO5O7HuKvfcAOKqaRbikkl/photo/AF1QipManRBvVVH76DW_LfrZHUa7L74PlD56Kd5eD9zp "before upgrade"

![2]: https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipP3gJTQoAlJNM5tB3VO5O7HuKvfcAOKqaRbikkl/photo/AF1QipOKX3422yh88cTZmrPMeRvzWm8ykShDda1mPELi "after upgrade"

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./code/themes/dark-unica.js"></script>



        var gaugeOptions = {

            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge'
            },

            title: null,

            pane: {
                center: ['50%', '60%'],
                size: '70%',
                startAngle: -135,
                endAngle: 135,
                background: {
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                    innerRadius: '50%',
                    outerRadius: '100%',
                    shape: 'arc'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                enable: true,
                shared: true,
                outside: true,

            },

            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                stops: [
                    [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                    [0.9, '#DF5353']  // red
                ],
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                tickPixelInterval: 400,
                tickWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    y: -35
                },
                labels: {
                    y: 16
                }

            },

            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        y: -10,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        useHTML: true
                    }
                }
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        };

        // The CPU temp gauge
        $('#temp-cpu').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 60,
                showFirstLabel: false,
                showLastLabel: false,

                title: {
                    text: 'CPU'
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Temp.',
                data: [{
                    radius: '100%',
                    innerRadius: '50%',
                }],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div><span style="font-color:' + 
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span>' +
                   '°</div>'},

                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>',
                    valueSuffix: ' ºC',
                },
            }]

        }));

        // The HDD Temp gauge
        $('#temp-hdd').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 60,
                showFirstLabel: false,
                showLastLabel: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'HDD'
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Temp.',
                data: [{
                    radius: '100%',
                    innerRadius: '50%',
                }],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div><span style="font-color:' + 
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span>' +
                   '°</div>'},
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>',
                    valueSuffix: ' °C',
                },
            }]

        }));

        // The CPU load gauge
        $('#load-cpu').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                showFirstLabel: false,
                showLastLabel: false,

                title: {
                    text: 'CPU'
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Load',
                data: [{
                    radius: '100%',
                    innerRadius: '50%',
                }],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div><span style="font-color:' + 
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span>' +
                   '%</div>'},
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>',
                    valueSuffix: ' %',
                },
            }]

        }));


        setInterval(function () {


            // CPU Temp
            var chart = $('#temp-cpu').highcharts(),
            point,
            newVal,
            inc;

            if (chart) {
                point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                newVal =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("cpu_temp_box").value);
                point.update(newVal);
                chart.redraw();
            }

            //HDD Temp
            chart = $('#temp-hdd').highcharts();
            if (chart) {
                point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                newVal =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("hdd_temp_box").value);
                point.update(newVal);
                chart.redraw();
            }

            //CPU Load
            chart = $('#load-cpu').highcharts();
            if (chart) {
                point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                newVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cpu_busy_box").value);
                point.update(newVal);
                chart.redraw();
            }
```

Comment: Your images don't seem to be available for viewing, and also require login. Could you host them somewhere else?

Comment: Try in all three charts to change from `data: [{ radius: '100%', innerRadius: '50%', }]` to `data: [{ y: 0 }]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series data, which is currently set like this:

```
data: [{
  radius: '100%',
  innerRadius: '50%',
}]
```

Appears to [work in version 4.2.5](https://jsfiddle.net/qkwj5z7x/), but [not work in newer versions](https://jsfiddle.net/qkwj5z7x/1/).

This is probably because you supply no Y-value, so I suggest setting it to:

```
data: [0]
```